# How to add .NET Core 2.1 project reference in Unit Test project built on .NET Framework 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core, microsoft-fakes

I want to write unit test cases for a project which was built using `.net core 2.1`.

Unit test project using `.net framework 4.6.1`.

I am facing below issue while adding `.net core app reference` in `Unit test project`.

> Project '..\MSNetCoreApp.csproj' targets 'netcoreapp2.1'.It cannot be referenced by a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1'. MSUnitTests

Comment: You can't. The error message is clear. Use an appropriately versioned unit test project.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done.

Your `MSNetCoreApp` is compiled to run on .NET Core Framework, while your test project needs to run on full .NET Framework. They are not compatible.

You need to create new test project targeting `netcoreapp2.1` or to convert existing one.

Only class libraries targeting `netstandard` can be referenced by both `netcore` and `netframework` assemblies.